# JavaScript slice without parameters or brackets (code in CodeMirror sql-hint.js)

Tags: javascript, slice, codemirror

I am adapting the sql-hint.js code from the excellent [CodeMirror](https://codemirror.net/index.html) to my evil designs...

But I have encountered a line of JavaScript which is beyond me. I don't understand it, and cannot find anything that explains it.

It is line 34 in CodeMirror-master\addon\hint\sql-hint.js and it looks like this:

```
function getItem(list, item) {
     if (!list.slice) return list[item];     // <--- THIS LINE!!!!!
for (var i = list.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) if (getText(list[i]) == item)
    return list[i];
}
```

The command I do not understand is this:

```
if (!list.slice)
```

There are no parameters, and there are no brackets.
What on earth is going on here? I assume magic...

Please note that it does **not** say this:

```
if (!list.slice())
```

Comment: checks for the existence of slice, be it object, string, date, or ... **function** - that code will be true if `list.slice` is not anything false (false, 0, '', undefined, null)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JavaScript is a truthy/falsy language which means that we can assert whether or not a given object is true or false based on some criteria. In JavaScript the values that always report as false are: `false`, `0 (zero)` `"" (empty string)`, `null`, `undefined`, `NaN`.

The check here is looking to find out if `list.slice` is `undefined` and if so, is returning the list item at index `item`.

If you were to `console.log(list.slice)` you'd expect something like `function () {}`. We wouldn't want to call the function though since that would fail if `slice` was undefined.

Answer (score 1):

If you have

```
var obj = {
    foo: function () { return "string"; }
}
```

And you want to check whether `foo` and `bar` exist in obj, you'd need to do this:

```
console.log(obj.foo); // returns "function obj.foo()"
console.log(obj.bar); // returns "undefined"
```

You can't define interfaces in javascript so you have no other choice to check whether a property/method exists in an object.

And as @Jamie said, anything not falsy is evaluated as truth, so in the example above

- `obj.foo` is `function obj.foo()`, and it's `true` when used in an `if` statement (or any boolean context)
- `obj.bar` is `undefined` and will be `false` when used in an `if` statement

An alternative to what you do is the following:

```
if(typeof list.slice === "function") return list[item];
```

This is longer but more obvious.

Not sure but I think you can do this:

```
if(typeof list === "array" || typeof list === "object")
    return list[item];
```

which is most self-explanatory, I think.